# AWS elasticsearch service throws Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to https:80 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am currently trying to configure AWS’ elasticsearch service in my Rails v 5.1.4 application. I am using `elasticsearch-rails 6.0.0.` The issue I am currently getting I believe is with how my elasticsearch client is being set up in my initializer. One restriction I have is I can’t use the `faraday_middleware-aws-signers-v4` gem to help communication between my AWS elastisearch instance and my app. I am attempting to do this with just `aws-sdk-rails 1.0.1.` Since this server is in the same security group as the elasticsearch instance I am assuming I don't need to pass in credentials.

Here is the my error:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to https:80 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:906:in `rescue in block in connect'`
```

Here is my `initializers/elasticsearch.rb`:

```
config = {
  hosts: {host: 'https://search-epl-elasticsearch-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com', port: '80'},
  transport_options: {
    request: { timeout: 5 }
  }
}
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise it's months later, but it appears you're configuring elasticsearch with an https url and telling it to use port 80 instead of 443.  Try this instead:

```
config = {
  url: 'https://search-epl-elasticsearch-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com',
  transport_options: {
    request: { timeout: 5 }
  }
}
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```